# How to connect Python Flask CAS server to angular application?

Tags: python, angular, authentication

I have the python server (Flask more precisely) up and running and it is connecting correctly to my CAS server, redirecting to CAS login, and returning correct user data upon login. This is relevant code from flask server:

```
app.secret_key = "SOMESECRETKEY"

cas_client = CASClient(
    version=3,
    service_url="http://localhost:5000/login?next=%2Fprofile",
    server_url='https://django-cas-ng-demo-server.herokuapp.com/cas/'

)

@app.route("/profile")
def profile(method=["GET"]):
    if "username" in session:
        jawt = jwt.encode(session["user_attributes"], app.secret_key, algorithm="HS256")
    return redirect("http://localhost:4200/?accessToken=" + jawt)
```

The data is returned to the angular page, via GET method redirect (see code above). I don't want to send the accessToken by GET method, but rather, I want to store it in localStorage. How can I do that, from python, but WITHOUT first sending it as GET parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, the token is returned by whatever route implements the login functionality, but if that's not possible you can create a specific route just for that and save it in localStorage:

```py
from flask import jsonify

@app.route("/token")
def token(method=["GET"]):
    if "username" not in session:
        abort(403)
    token = jwt.encode(session["user_attributes"], app.secret_key, algorithm="HS256")
    return jsonify(token=token)
```

and then create another route to return profile details:

```py
import requests
from flask import jsonify, request

@app.route("/profile")
def profile(method=["GET"]):
    token = get_token_from_authorization_header(request)
    qs = {"accessToken": token}
    resp = requests.get("http://localhost:4200", params=qs)
    if not resp.ok:
        abort(403)
    return resp.json()
```

Comment: Good recommendation but cas actually has its own portal page, so it is not just a simple get/post request, but rather, a series of redirects.

Comment: ah, sorry. I've never heard of it, but from the looks of it, it's a standard django app. Do you have control over it? If yes, you could just build a django view to serve the profile details

Comment: Hi. Your response actually is a good way for the approach, so one request to get the token, other request to do the actual call to API. I am looking for a way to be more indirect, i.e. some other way other than just returning the JWT as a simple json text response. I want to maybe find out how to set JWT from python directly, e.g. in localstorage from python directly, or, some response header value maybe.